# Game Center App Update Leaderboards stay the same?

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

When I go to update my app, will the old leaderboards that I created in previous versions stay the same in future updates for my app or will I have to create new leaderboards to follow with every update?

Answer (score 0):

They'd stay the same unless you did anything explicitly. Just don't do anything and push the update.

Comment: Ok, so if I don't want to change anything to them, I just leave everything the same and they will stay the same in future updates?

Comment: Yes, there *may* be options to reset them, I don't know (it has been a few months since I've last submitted/updated a Game Center-enabled game to iTunes Connect), but a few months ago, absolutely nothing changed on leaderboards unless you explicitly told so. I doubt that behavior has changed ever since, as it would be illogical. Do nothing and you should be safe with your current leaderboard score on the next version.