# Game Centre Integration with App Updates - iTunes Connet

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, game-center

I just released my first App in the App Store and Version 1.0 has been available for a few days now.

I'm now in the process of pushing a small update which fixes a few minor bugs using iTunes Connect.

Everything is fine and the new version 1.1 build has been uploaded.

My question is, I've re-enabled Game Center in the Version 1.1 using the green switch button in Version 1.1 but it says "You don't have any new leaderboards for this app."

Do I need to make a new leaderboard? or will it use the previous version's (1.0) leaderboard without re-adding it to the latest version?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26939057/game-center-app-update-leaderboards-stay-the-same), but the details are sparse and possibly outdated.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand how 1.0 has leaderboards if you're just adding GameCenter in 1.1...

Comment: Sorry, it's probably my way of wording things. V1.0 does have leaderboards, but when releasing an update you have to re-enable them... My question is, will it use the previous leaderboard that was approved with V1.0 seems I can't add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was obviously being dumb.

Once the `Game Center` is enabled in the Update on iTunes Connect, it says:

```
"You don't have any new leaderboards for this app."
```

The key word being: "You don't have any **new** leaderboards for this app.", thus assuming your update doesn't include any new or additional leaderboards from the previous version/build, then you don't need to do anything more than enable Game Center.

All scored/points will continue going to the leaderboard declared and authenticated in the previous version.

I hope this helps.